# Highcharts with react Error: "missingModule" with chart type of "timeline"

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to generate a "timeline" chart using Highcharts with react. The code is as following:

```
import React from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
HighchartMore(Highcharts)

const options = {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      type: 'timeline',
      height: '900px'
    },
    series: [{
      data:data
    }]
}

return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

However, there is an ERROR: Error: Highcharts error #17: [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=timeline](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=timeline)

Need help!

Answer (score 3):

As the error says - the `Timeline` module is missing.

Take a look at the official Timeline demo - as you can see there is an additional module attached for timeline.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-timeline/connector-styles

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/timeline.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

How to add the modules in the Highcharts React wrapper you can find here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module

Answer (score 2):

First you have to import timeline chart -

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import timeline from 'highcharts/modules/timeline';
```

Then you have to initialize it -

```
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
timeline(Highcharts);
```

Then you have to set options -

```
const options = {
        title: {
            text: "My chart",
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'timeline',
                data: data,
            },
        ],
    };
```

Then you have to render it -

```
<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
```

So the full code will be -

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import timeline from 'highcharts/modules/timeline';

const Page = () => {

  const options = {
          title: {
              text: "My chart",
          },
          series: [
              {
                  type: 'timeline',
                  data: [1, 2, 3],
              },
          ],
      };
  }

  return (
          <div className={styles.container}>
                <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
          </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1):

***-= WORKING EXAMPLE =-***
[demo codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-2gyl2x?file=/demo.jsx)

I built a demo for those who need not just a timeline, there is also column range, bullets, etc...

and this solution solves this error
`Highcharts error #17 https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/17 https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-2gyl2x?file=/demo.jsx`

And for your convenience, if you are not sure if there exists (in HighCharts node module) a module you need, so you can go to your project in VSCode (or whatever you use) and look on this screenshot, so you will find (or not) what you are looking for
[image]